# Is it a good idea to have masters and workers running on the same node in a small Spark cluster for HA?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing

I need to set up an Apache Spark cluster in Standalone mode for a production environment. For this task, I only have three available nodes. Each node has:

- 128GB RAM
- 24 CPU cores

There is no example documentation available for small clusters like the one I need to configure. Indirectly, I have deduced that it is recommended to have a separate servers for worker and master nodes, but I'm not sure if this is really the case.

Without having a clear direction yet, I have thought of these two options:

##### First option:

- Node 1 -> Master and Driver
- Node 2 -> Worker
- Node 3 -> Worker

###### Pros:

- Simple to implement. I would use FILESYSTEM recovery for high availability.
- The processes initiated by each master and worker would be isolated.

###### Cons:

- Recovery would take a long time if the hardware of the master node is damaged. A new server would need to be configured or the existing one repaired.
- I would be wasting the resources of the master node.

##### Second option:

- Node 1 -> Master and Worker
- Node 2 -> Master and Worker
- Node 3 -> Master and Worker

###### Pros:

- Installation is a bit more complicated. I would use ZooKeeper for high availability.
- Recovery would be immediate. According to the documentation, it takes 1 to 2 minutes.

###### Cons:

- The processes initiated by the masters and workers are on the same server. I'm not really sure if this is a problem.

I have tried searching in Spark forums and official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Master usually doesn't need much compute, it only tracks worker health, similar case for driver if you're not using any action like collect. Major heavy lifting is done by workers and executors if your spark app is coded as per spark pattern where you encourage parallelism.
Start with a 1 core master and a 1 core driver if it's a batch job, or at the most a 2 core driver if it's a streaming job.